# Direct URL routing returns not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I  have deployed two apps on heroku and I'm facing the same issue with both of them, I can access all the routes from within the app (when I click on buttons and preform actions) but when I try to access them from direct URL I get a 404 error.

So I must be doing something very weird in my routes but I don't know what is it.

Here is an a link of one of the sites :[shoppy](https://shoppy-ecom.herokuapp.com/)

Here is the routes for it on my index.js file :

```
app.use("/", routerUser);
app.use("/cart", routerCart);
app.use("/api/products", routerProduct);
app.use("/user/order", routerOrder);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/ecom/build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/ecom/build" + "index.html");
});
```

Here are the routes in routerProduct.js:  Note that I can access the route `https://shoppy-ecom.herokuapp.com/products/women` when I click on the women section but get 404 when I try to access it from URL.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { VerifyToken } = require("../middlewares/tokenVerify.js");
const {
  getProducts,
  deleteProduct,
  addProduct,
  updateProduct,
  getSingleProduct,
} = require("../controllers/product.js");

router.route("/").get(getProducts).post(VerifyToken, addProduct);
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(getSingleProduct)
  .patch(VerifyToken, updateProduct)
  .delete(VerifyToken, deleteProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

React routes :

```js
import {Home,ShoppingCat,ProductView, Register,Login,Cart} from './routes'
import {Routes,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const App = () => {
  const user=useSelector(state => state.user.currentUser)
  return <div>
    <Routes>
    
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route  exact path="/products/:category" element={ <ShoppingCat/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={ <ProductView/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/cart" element={ <Cart/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/login" element={user?.length!==0?<Navigate to='/'/>: <Login/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/register" element={user?.length!==0? <Navigate to='/'/> :<Register/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You've tagged [tag:reactjs]. Do you have a React app? And is it _React_ routing, or Express routing that's failing?

Comment: I have added the react routes, it is the React Routing  that is failing

Comment: "it is the React Routing that is failing"—that makes sense. Let me see if I can find a reference question...

Comment: I have tried the solution of creating a static.json file in my root and add this script to it :`{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
     "/**": "index.html"
  }` but it didn't work for me